# AdonisJs User Authentication for User Login Fails

Tags: node.js, authentication, adonis.js

I have started building my first NodeJs app. I am usinf AdonisJs framework.

I have created a simple user registration page from where user gets registered successfully. After that when I go to login page to log that user in, it's `request.auth.attempt(email, password)` method won't authenticate the existing user. Here's what I have coded so far:

## config/auth.js

```
authenticator: 'session',

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Session Authenticator
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Session authenticator will make use of sessions to maintain the login
  | state for a given user.
  |
  */
  session: {
    serializer: 'Lucid',
    model: 'App/Model/User',
    scheme: 'session',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  },
```

## routes.js

```
const Route = use('Route')

// Register
Route.get('register', 'AuthController.showRegisterPage')
Route.post('register', 'AuthController.register')

// Login
Route.get('login', 'AuthController.showLoginPage')
Route.post('login', 'AuthController.login')

// Logout
Route.get('logout', 'AuthController.logout')
```

## AuthController.js/register

```
/**
     * Handle user registration
     */
    * register(request, response) {

        // validate form input
        const rules = {
            name: 'required',
            username: 'required|unique:users',
            email: 'required|email|unique:users',
            password: 'required|confirmed|min:6'
        }

        const messages = {
            'name.required': 'Name field is required.',
            'username.required': 'Username field is required.',
            'username.unique': 'Username field must have a unique value.',
            'email.required': 'Email field is required.',
            'email.unique': 'Email field must have a unique value.',
            'password.required': 'Password field is required.',
            'password.confirmed': 'Password/Confirm Password fields does not match.'
        }

        const validation = yield Validator.validateAll(request.all(), rules, messages)

        // show error messages upon validation fail
        if (validation.fails()) {
            yield request
                .withAll()
                .andWith({ errors: validation.messages() })
                .flash()

            return response.redirect('back')
        }

        const user = new User()
        user.name = request.input('name')
        user.username = request.input('username')
        user.email = request.input('email')
        user.password = yield Hash.make(request.input('password'))
        yield user.save()

        yield response.sendView('auth.register', {message: {type: 'success', text: 'Registration successful. You can login now.'} })

    }
```

## AuthController.js/login

```
/**
     * Handle user authentication
     */
    * login(request, response) {

        const email = request.input('email')
        const password = request.input('password')

        // validate form input
        const rules = {
            email: 'required|email',
            password: 'required'
        }

        const messages = {
            'email.required': 'Email field is required.',
            'password.required': 'Password field is required.'
        }

        const validation = yield Validator.validateAll(request.all(), rules, messages)

        // show error messages upon validation fail
        if (validation.fails()) {
            yield request
                .withAll()
                .andWith({ errors: validation.messages() })
                .flash()

            return response.redirect('back')
        }

        try {

            yield request.auth.attempt(email, password)
            response.route('/')

        } catch (e) {

           yield response.sendView('auth.login', {message: {type: 'error', text: 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.'} })

        }

    }
```

## app/Model/User

```
'use strict'

const Lucid = use('Lucid')
const Hash = use('Hash')

class User extends Lucid {

  static boot () {
    super.boot()

    /**
     * Hashing password before storing to the
     * database.
     */
    this.addHook('beforeCreate', function * (next) {
      this.password = yield Hash.make(this.password)
      yield next
    })
  }

  apiTokens () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Model/Token')
  }

}

module.exports = User
```

Every time I try to log in, it always executes the `catch` part in login method. I don't have any idea what's going on. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are hashing the password twice.

If you look at your `User` Model there's a hook to hash the password with `bcrypt` before creating it into the database.

On your registration workflow you are also hashing the password.

```
const user = new User()
user.name = request.input('name')
user.username = request.input('username')
user.email = request.input('email')
user.password = yield Hash.make(request.input('password')) // here
yield user.save().
```

This is why it doesn't work.
You must remove the hashing part on your controller method.

As a side note that Adonis 4.0 is released so if you start a new project you may want to use this version instead of using 3.2.

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks a lot :)